# writing 3 bits at a time to binary file in C

Tags: c, binaryfiles, bit-shift

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LOQSN.png)

hello, i have a list of locations as described in the image stored in a linked list. every node has an unsigned char in the size of 2(chessPos in the code) - the first location represents a row and the second a col. for example the first node: row = 'C', col = '5' and so on. the list is passed through the function i dont need to built it.

i need to write the data to a binary file, when each row or col is written in 3 bits. so 'C' will be written as 010 and right after '5' will be written as 100 (the 3 bits written represent the row/col -1, thats why '5' is represnted by 100 which is 4 in binary).

the difficulty is that every byte is 8 bits and every time i write a byte to the file it contains 6 bits which represt a row and a col, and 2 bits of the next byte.

how can i make it work?

thanks

this is my code so far:

```
      typedef char chessPos[2];
    
    
    typedef struct _chessPosArray {
        unsigned int size;
        chessPos* positions;
    }chessPosArray;
    
    typedef struct _chessPosCell {
        chessPos position;
        struct _chessPosCell* next;
    }chessPosCell;
    
    typedef struct _chessPosList {
        chessPosCell* head;
        chessPosCell* tail;
    }chessPosList;

 

    void function_name(char* file_name, chessPosList* pos_list)
{

    FILE* file;
    short list_len;
    int i = 0;
    unsigned char row, col, byte_to_file, next_byte;
    chessPosCell* curr = pos_list->head;


    file = fopen(file_name, "wb"); /* open binary file to writing */
    checkFileOpening(file);

    
    while (curr != NULL)
    {
        row = curr->position[0] - 'A' - 17; /* 'A' ---> '1' ---> '0' */
        col = curr->position[1] - 1; /* '4' ---> '3' */

        if (remain < 6)
        { 
            curr = curr->next;
            remain += 8;                
        }

        if (i > 1)
        {
            i = 0;
        }

        if (curr->next != NULL)
        {
            next_byte = curr->next->position[i] >> (remain - 7);
            byte_to_file = ((row << (remain - 3)) | (col << (remain - 6))) | (next_byte);
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            byte_to_file = ((row << (remain - 3)) | (col << (remain - 6)));
        }

        fwrite(&byte_to_file, sizeof(unsigned char), 1, file);

        remain -= 6;                    
             
    }
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem with what you currently have?

Comment: The least addressable unit in both memory and files is a single *byte* (on all PC-like systems). If the three bits you want to write are part of a byte with all the rest of the bits irrelevant, then you can write that byte, but it's not possible to write single bits.

Comment: You will need to buffer all output in a byte-array (an array or allocated block of `unsigned char`) and when done write it out byte-by-byte to the file. There is no ability to write less than a byte to a file. In other words, you will need to do all the bit-packing in each byte before writing that byte to file.

Comment: files are block devices, so writing even one byte is less efficient, let alone a few bits. You should read the whole buffer, update it and write it to file at once

Comment: @mkrieger1 it only works for the first byte written

Comment: If you really need three bits at a time, you have to marshal them into a set of bytes. You need at least three bytes (24 bits) to be even with bits and bytes.

Comment: I doubt file size is really going to be much of an issue. I'd just write each position in a full byte (wasting 5 bits). But that makes it easy to read and write. Worry about efficiency if it's necessary, but makes things easy first.

Comment: Unless you're trying to comply with an existing data format, this sounds like a case of premature optimization. How many entries are there in your list of positions, and how much do you really stand to gain by saving 5 bits/location compared to using a `char` for each location?

Comment: What is the `- 17` for when setting `row`?

Comment: Just to expand on what @Caleb is saying. It is often simpler, more flexible, easier to debug etc. to use a standard textual dataformat like CSV or JSON than a binary format. And if you *really* need to save space, post processing the data with a generic file compression tool would probably give better results than your homemade bitpacking.

Answer (score 1):

> how can i make it work?

Since each location requires both a column and a row, you can actually think of a location as a single 6-bit value in which the lowest 3 bits are the row and the high 3 bits are the column. If you think of it that way, then the problem is a little bit simpler in that you're actually just talking about base-64 encoding/decoding, and there are lots of open-source implementations available if you really want to pack the data into the smallest possible space.

That said, I'd encourage you to consider whether your problem really requires minimizing the storage space. You could instead store those locations as characters, either using 4 bits for row and 4 for column, continue treating locations as 6-bit values and just ignore the two extra bits. Unless you're storing a huge number of these locations, the benefit of saving two bits per location isn't likely to matter.

Answer (score 0):

> how can i make it work?

Well, first start with a good abstraction. Anyway, it's actually pretty simple:

- let's take a 16-bit/2-byte buffer and a bit position within the buffer

  - it's way easier when the buffer is continues (`uint16_t`) instead of two separate bytes (`unsigned char byte_to_file, next_byte`). The `next_byte` bits just shift themselves and `byte_to_file` can be extracted with a mask.
- I "see" in my imagination MSB on the left and LSB on the right
- for each new 6-bits push it to the most left position that is not set yet

  - so shift of  16-6  minus the position
- if we filled more then 8 bits

  - take one byte and output it
  - and shift the buffer 8 bits to the left

Here's a sample program that prints `Hello world\n`:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct bitwritter {
    FILE *out;
    // our buffer for bits
    uint16_t buf;
    // the count of set bits within buffer counting from MSB
    unsigned char pos;
};

struct bitwritter bitwritter_init(FILE *out) {
   return (struct bitwritter){ .out = out };
}

int bitwritter_write_6bits(struct bitwritter *t, unsigned char bits6) {
   // we always write starting from MSB
   unsigned char toshift = 16 - 6 - t->pos;
   // just a mask with 6 bits
   bits6 &= 0x3f;
   t->buf |= bits6 << toshift;
   t->pos += 6;
   // do we have whole byte?
   if (t->pos >= 8) {
      // extract the byte - note it's in MSB
      unsigned char towrite = t->buf >> 8;
      // shift out buffer
      t->buf <<= 8;
      t->pos -= 8;
      // write output
      if (fwrite(&towrite, sizeof(towrite), 1, t->out) != 1) {
             return -1;
      }
      return 1;
   }
   return 0;
}

int main() {
    struct bitwritter bw = bitwritter_init(stdout);
    // echo 'Hello world' | xxd -c1 -p | while read l; do python -c "print(\"{0:08b}\".format(0x$l))"; done | paste -sd '' | sed -E 's/.{6}/0b&,\n/g'
    unsigned char data[] = {
        0b010010,
        0b000110,
        0b010101,
        0b101100,
        0b011011,
        0b000110,
        0b111100,
        0b100000,
        0b011101,
        0b110110,
        0b111101,
        0b110010,
        0b011011,
        0b000110,
        0b010000,
        0b001010,
    };
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(data); ++i) {
        bitwritter_write_6bits(&bw, data[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Adding an extra call to `bitwritter_write_6bits(&bw, 0);` after the `for` loop will flush out the last few bits of data if necessary (i.e. if the number of 6-bit chunks is not a multiple of 4).